# How to apply smoothing on speech segments concatenation using NAudio?

Tags: algorithm, text-to-speech, naudio, smoothing

I'm doing speech segments concatenation to produce final speech (Test to speech task), I want apply smoothing on these segments to make the final result more natural.
What is the best smoothing technique for this case? and how can I apply it using NAudio library

P.S:
I need a sample code or any tutorial for applying any smoothing technique on wav

Answer (score 0):

Fade one side out while you fade the other side in.  Try linear fade and logarithmic.

EDIT:  Here are the steps you might have to do to accomplish this:

We will call the first clip C1 and the second clip C2.  Call the lengths of the clips tC1 and tC2.  You are trying to combine them in a smooth way.  First determine how long you want the fade to last.  This is probably a matter of milliseconds.  Perhaps start with 200 milliseconds.  Call this tFade.

```
1. Do the fade-out on the end of C1.
2. Do the fade-in on the start of C2.
3. Pad the end of C1 with tC2-tFade of silence
4. Pad the start of C2 with tC1-tFade of silence
5. Add the padded clips together (at this point, they are the same length: tC1+tC2-tFade)
```

Comment: could you give me a reference, I'm purely beginner in this.

Comment: I don't know how to do a fade in NAudio -- I have never used that.  But it is a pretty basic operation.  What do you mean by a reference?